# Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 94371840 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 42240 bytes) in /home/dh_w7t9sk/morleywines.com/wp-content/plugins/

Tags: fatal-error

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 94371840 bytes exhausted (tried to
>   allocate 42240 bytes) in
>   /home/dh_w7t9sk/morleywines.com/wp-content/plugins/js_composer/include/params/iconpicker/iconpicker.php
>   on line 720

I can't seem to get back into my dashboard. Can you help me please

Comment: I experienced the same issue, after I delete the Js-composer plugin, my site is back

Answer (score 2):

Add below code in `wp-config.php` file.

```
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M');
```

For more details check "Increasing memory allocated to PHP" here  https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php

Answer (score -2):

THe error message indicates an issue with the 'js-composer' plugin. Rename that folder to get control of the system.

Comment: actually wrong. that plugin is just the first one that request the additional memory which can not be made available, but that do not indicate that it is the one that consumes unreasonable amount of memory.  If that plugin is not the cause all you will do is move the error to another plugin

Comment: That's possible, but still the first place I would look. If error still occurs, then I'd start disabling other plugins.  The OP didn't indicate that this was a new problem on a new installation, so MEMORY_LIMIT might not fix it either (although a good thing to check). If the OP had been able to access admin before, then chances are it is a recently added plugin. The error message is a good place to start. Although looking at 'surrounding' error messages might also be a good idea, but that info was not provided.

Comment: It is also possible that the site was always close to the limit and just crossed it due to some change in settings. The problem with disabling plugins is that (hopefully) they serve some required functionality that can not be disabled.

Comment: in the end https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/39340/memory-issues-fatal-error-out-of-memory-plugins?rq=1 is the only answer that can be given for all of the "out of memory" errors

Comment: The answer that Mark Kaplun (https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/23970/mark-kaplun )  references is very similar to my answer. Disable plugins to see if that makes a difference. And that answer continues to recommend adding plugins one at a time to see if the problem comes back. It may be a cumulative affect, as mentioned in that answer. But my initial answer about removing plugins is valid; as indicated by the answer that Mr Kaplun seems to recommend over mine.  Which indicates to me that his (assumed) downvote on my answer is not valid...by his own admission.